# Bubble sort NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have managed with some help to sort my NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries using the NSArray function **sortedArrayUsingComparator** However the Array I am wanting to sort is no just based off one value.

There are two values a startdate and finishdate, Currently I am only sorting by startdate so my array appears sorted untill you look at the enddate and see that they are incorrect.

Current format.

```
(start / end)
0 / 1996
0 / 1991
1992 / 1995
1993 / 1999
1993 / 1991
```

when in fact I would like to achieve something like this

```
(start / end)
0 / 1991
0 / 1996
1992 / 1995
1993 / 1991
1993 / 1999
```

This is my code at the current moment

```
 // try sorting years
    NSString const * myStartDate = @"DATESTART";
    NSString const * myEndDate = @"DATEEND";

    NSArray *sortedArray = [resultantArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSDictionary *dictA = a;
        NSDictionary *dictB = b;

        NSNumber *startDate1 = dictA[myStartDate];
        NSNumber *startDate2 = dictB[myStartDate];

        return [startDate1 compare:startDate2];

    }];
```

This generates the first example of sorting I gave you, What I am hoping for with a little help is to sort it so that anything with the same start date the end date is sorted into order.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is using an array of NSSortDescriptors not viable for you for some reason?

Comment: @Eugene I am reading up about NSSortDescriptor now.. but the thing is I get lost with the fact that I am sorting start and end..

Comment: just use something like [arr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor key:startDate asc:YES], [NSSortDescriptor key:endDate asc:YES]]]; - syntax is incorrect, I don't have the access to the ide now

Comment: okay thank going to try that now.

Comment: okay I gave it a try after the comma i get this error **No known class method for selector 'key:asc:'**

Comment: @HurkNburkS Eugene is using short hand;  look at the declaration of the NSSortDescriptor class or the docs to see the full method name.

Answer (score 0):

When I first set out trying to figure out how to sort a NSMutableArray using two elements of the NSDictionarys inside the array I did not understand NSSortDescriptors so I overlooked the examples given here

**https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001845-BAJEAIEE**

For my particular problem **Listing 2** was the perfect solution.. So i coded it up for myself and it worked perfectly!!!!

Here is my solution.

```
NSSortDescriptor *yearStartDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"YEARSTART" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *yearEndDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"YEARFINISH" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[yearStartDesc, yearEndDesc];
NSArray *newSortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSLog(@"%@", newSortedArray);
```

Just like to thank everyone for helping me out.